# Subjective questions: Book recommendations

Tags: discussion, scope, tags

This needs an introduction:

I just wanted to ask for book recommendations about alpinism and therefore had a search first. I noticed there are 6 questions with a **[books]**-tag but the tag isn't really available, so I created it. I think it is useful.

Nonetheless, a similar question got closed: [Books to inspire you to get out in nature](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/books-to-inspire-you-to-get-out-in-nature)

I know we are on SE network and on SO a question this subjective would be a no-go. For sure there is no *correct* answer and the list of answers could be quite long. Nonetheless I would like to allow this to get a comprehensive outdoor information platform (and more fame for The Great Outdoors).

Of course this is not up to me, just wanted to give you guys a thought ;)

**edit**

Just noticed a similar question which wasn't closed: [What good factual books have you read on an outdoors topic?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/what-good-factual-books-have-you-read-on-an-outdoors-topic)

I like the idea of making it a community wiki, should we always handle it like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to be careful that questions like this don't become too **subjective** or **broad**.

Asking for a book recommendation on a specific topic I think is fine.

I.e.

```
Can anyone recommend a guide to the alps?
What walking books are available for the Lake District?
```

Questions such as:

```
What's your favourite outdoor book?
What's your favourite outdoor autobiography?
etc.
```

(I feel) should be discouraged and closed.

I think we should also discourage books asking for advice on things that the site itself should address.

```
Can you recommend a book that will show me how to tie a figure of eight knot?

No, but I can show you how to tie a figure of eight knot.
```

These, I feel should be re-worded and answered. This is the same as simply asking for off site links. We're the repository, we shouldn't be handing this responsibility off to other people/sites.